# How can i apply same "solver" to every column in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I try to apply same solver to every column.
Here's my data

[image]

So S1 and S2 is related with  all the other variables

delta_10+delta_11*X1+delta_21*x2=S1

delta_20+delta_21*x1+delta_22*x2=S2

So I need to make S1 and S2 zero by changing x1 and x2

Simply I need to solve 2 unknown 2 equation in a single line
 here's my vba code but It doesn't work

```
Sub MultipleSolver()
Dim i As Integer
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate
For i = 5 To 5
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$AB$" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Z$" & i & ",$AA$" & i
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AC$" & i, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
SolverSolve True
Next i
End Sub
```

I could not understand what's wrong with it

```
Sub Makro6()
'
' Makro6 Makro
'

'
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AB$5", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Z$5:$AA$5", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AC$5", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AB$5", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Z$5:$AA$5", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AB$5", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Z$5:$AA$5", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AB$5", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Z$5:$AA$5", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
End Sub
```

Comment: `"$Z$:$AA$" & i` is not a valid range.

Comment: Sorry I realized now I changed it above but still not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: does nothing I click run and nothing happens edit: I put a recorded macro for one row I need to put it in a loop for rows 5:150